# Pandas dataframe to_html cell alignment

Tags: python, html, pandas, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a Pandas data frame that look like this:

```
    X     Y        Z
  abc   0.2     -1.5
  efg   0.8     -1.4
```

I would like to use the to_html() method to generate a HTML out of this, but I would like to have column X to be left aligned, column Y and Z right aligned. In addition, I would like to make the negative float numbers to be shown as (1.5) and (1.4) and font color is set to red for these. It looks like there is a formatter option in to_html() and it seems I can get the negative numbers to be shown with parentheses, but I cannot figure out how to set the alignment and font color with this kind of condition.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure. I am able to get the negative numbers to show with parentheses via:  formatter = lambda x: '({:,.0f})'.format(fabs(x)) if x < 0 else '{:,.0f}'.format(fabs(x)), and then pd.options.display.float_format = formatter. When you call df.to_html(), the negative numbers will now be shown in parentheses. But, then how to set these things to red for the negative numbers, and how to set only the numeric columns to be right aligned, that I cannot figure out how.

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this with `to_html`. There's an [open PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10250) working on this that will be more flexible. Should go into the next release.

Comment: Can be easily done with.
See my solution here.
[Align text in Pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046215/how-to-align-pandas-dataframe-column-number-text-in-jinja)

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on the same right justification issue.  It seems like it's a known issue (see @TomAugspurger's comment above).  I used your solution for displaying negative numbers with parentheses and was able to get the right justification to work.  However, there's a catch.  You need to have leading and trailing special characters for positive numbers to make this work.

First, figure out how many significant digits are in your longest floating point number you want right justified.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create pandas dataframe who's values are floats of varying length
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['Y', 'Z']) * 10000

#Determine the length of the longest float
y = len(str(max(abs(df.Y))))
z = len(str(max(abs(df.Z))))
if y > z:
    print(y)
else:
    print(z)
```

I'm not sure why `df.to_html(float_format = lambda x: '{:f}'.format(x)` won't right justify the result because floats default to right justified.

I've also tried to trick the function into right justification by adding leading spaces to make each float a minimum length so they'll line up on the right side `df.to_html(float_format = lambda x: '{:20f}'.format(x)`, but the leading spaces are omitted in the conversion to html for x < 20 significant digits (or however many you specify in the formatting statement).

The only way I've discovered that you can force leading spaces to be displayed in the html output for floats with fewer significant digits is to have special characters surrounding the float values and to specify the float's significant digit format as at least 1 longer than the actual longest value.  In the code block below, I made the float length a minimum of 20 characters, but it could be limited to the maximum (which we previously printed) plus 1.

```
#Convert df to html using '(x)' to denote -x and '+x+' to denote +x and right justify
df.to_html(float_format = lambda x: '({:20f})'.format(abs(x)) if x < 0 else '+{:20f}+'.format(abs(x)))
```

I'd welcome more elegant ways to do this.

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Python 3.5.2
- Pandas 0.18.1
- Numpy 1.11.1