# How to align Pandas DataFrame column number text in Jinja

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jinja2

I rendered a Pandas Dataframe to a webpage through Jinja but noticed the number column is left aligned.

When I tried applying the code below on the particular column to align right and loaded the webpage.

```
    df = df.style.set_properties(subset=["col1", "col2"], **{'text-align': 'right'})
```

It gives an error on the browser page. Funny enough it works perfectly when tried on Jupyter Notebook

```
    TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable
```

What I want is the number column to align right.
Anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get a Pandas or Jinja solution that worked. However I stumbled on a this and that solved the whole issue.

It was a CSS trick. I simply had to identify the specific column and applied the code below in my Style.css file.

```
    tbody>tr>:nth-child(5){
    text-align:right;
    }
```

The '5' being the column number.

Credit to [Charles Riebeling](https://support.awesome-table.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001393209-Add-style-to-specific-columns-or-rows-in-your-Table-view)

I believe this will be of help to someone.